# Spring cloud kubernetes with spring cloud loadbalancer

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

We recently moved from Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon to Spring Cloud LoadBalancer and using spring-cloud-kubernetes as discovery client.

What is the equivalent property for **spring.cloud.kubernetes.ribbon.mode** (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#ribbon-discovery-in-kubernetes) now? Since ribbon is no longer in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are working on providing SC LoadBalancer support now: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/516.